# boundary condition for embedded dielectric sphere

Tags: potential, boundary-conditions, dielectric

Is the potential across the boundary continuous for a dielectric sphere embedded in a dielectric material, so that the potential inside the sphere can be set equal to the potential outside of it at $r=R$ ?

Comment: What do you think and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most problems it suffices to think about the boundary conditions on the $D$ field. At an interface between two dielectrics we have that (in cgs units)
$$
\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{D} |_+ - \mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{D} |_- = 4\pi \sigma
$$
Where $\sigma$ is the surface charge density on the boudnary. Hence, 
$$
\epsilon_1 \mathbf{n}\cdot \nabla\phi|_+ - \epsilon_2 \mathbf{n}\cdot \nabla\phi|_- = -4\pi \sigma
$$
where $\epsilon_1$ is the dielectric constant of the material on the outside of the boundary and $\epsilon_2$ is the dielectric constant of the material inside of the boundary.